# Adding space between vowel and consonants?

Tags: java

Please can somebody help me to add space between vowels and consonants. The results should something like ae bc i

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        String str = "aebci";

        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        for (int i = 0; i < str.length()-1; i++) {
            if ((str.charAt(i) == 'a' || str.charAt(i) == 'e' || str.charAt(i) == 'i' || str.charAt(i) == 'o' || str.charAt(i) == 'u' ) &&
                 (str.charAt(i+1) != 'a' || str.charAt(i+1) != 'e' || str.charAt(i+1) != 'i' || str.charAt(i+1) != 'o' || str.charAt(i+1) != 'u' ))    {
                sb.append(" ");
            }
                sb.append(str.charAt(i));
        }
        System.out.println(sb.toString());;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to find all places when your string contains vowels and consonants near each other. It's possible using regexp:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String str = "aebci";
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("([aeiou][^aeiou])|([^aeiou][aeiou])");
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(str);

    StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();
    while (matcher.find()) {
        String group = matcher.group(); // two symbols
        matcher.appendReplacement(buffer, group.charAt(0) + " " + group.charAt(1));
    }
    matcher.appendTail(buffer);
    System.out.println(buffer.toString());
}
```

Output:

> ae bc i

Answer (score 1):

You need to make a few changes.

- you have written the wrong condition for "this character is not a vowel". You are essentially trying to negate the condition "is A OR is E OR is I OR is O OR is U". Using De Morgan's Law, the negation is "NOT A AND NOT E AND NOT I AND NOT O AND NOT U".
- you should first append `str.charAt(i)`, before the space. `str.charAt(i)` is the first character in the pair of characters that you are checking. You want a space to be inserted *after* this character if a condition is met, not *before*.
- You should also append the last character in the string after the for loop. The for loop doesn't do this because it only goes to the second-to-last character.
- You have only checked for the case of "vowel + consonant", but haven't checked for the case "consonant + vowel".

Making all those changes, your code should look like this:

```
    String str = "helloworld";

    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    for (int i = 0; i < str.length()-1; i++) {
        sb.append(str.charAt(i));
        // vowel + consonant case
        if ((str.charAt(i) == 'a' || str.charAt(i) == 'e' || str.charAt(i) == 'i' || str.charAt(i) == 'o' || str.charAt(i) == 'u' ) &&
                (str.charAt(i+1) != 'a' && str.charAt(i+1) != 'e' && str.charAt(i+1) != 'i' && str.charAt(i+1) != 'o' && str.charAt(i+1) != 'u' ))    {
            sb.append(" ");
        }
        // consonant + vowel case
        if ((str.charAt(i+1) == 'a' || str.charAt(i+1) == 'e' || str.charAt(i+1) == 'i' || str.charAt(i+1) == 'o' || str.charAt(i+1) == 'u' ) &&
                (str.charAt(i) != 'a' && str.charAt(i) != 'e' && str.charAt(i) != 'i' && str.charAt(i) != 'o' && str.charAt(i) != 'u' ))    {
            sb.append(" ");
        }
    }
    sb.append(str.charAt(str.length() - 1));
    System.out.println(sb.toString());
```